# Update MongoDB collection where field doesn't exist

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to update every record in a collection that doesn't contain a particular field.

The following query works using Mongo shell, but I am struggling to write this using the mongoDB.Driver in .Net.

```
db.Comments.update(
    { MemberRoleType: { $exists: false }},
    { $set: { MemberRoleType: 4 },
    { multi: true }
)
```

I've attempted various methods such as follows but can't achieve the result I'm looking for :

```
await comments.UpdateManyAsync(c => c.MemberRoleType == 0, Builders<Comment>.Update.Set(x => x.MemberRoleType, ContentRoleType.Online)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for exists

```
Builders<Comments>.Filter.Exists(x => x.MemberRoleType, false);
```

You should be able to use it like so

```
var filter = Builders<Comments>.Filter.Exists(x => x.MemberRoleType, false);
await comments.UpdateManyAsync(filter, Builders<Comment>.Update.Set(x => x.MemberRoleType, ContentRoleType.Online)));
```

Which in turn generates this query

```
{
        "q": {
            "MemberRoleType": {
                "$exists": false
            }
        },
        "u": {
            "$set": {
                "MemberRoleType": 4
            }
        },
        "multi": true
}
```

Comment: I'd even just come across the Exists filter but didn't notice that it had an override allowing you to pass false. Doh.